# Reverse Polish Notation Calc: subtraction of two positive numbers returning a minus?

Tags: java, subtraction

When performing a subtraction of two number on my Reverse Polish Notation Calculator, I get a minus number result, for example:

20 5 - = -15

Whereas, I would expect to see 15.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong with my code?

```
   else if (input.equals("-")) {
            int n1 = stack.pop();
            int n2 = stack.pop();
            int result = n1 - n2;

            stack.push((int)result);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle of a stack is LIFO (Last In First Out).

Therefore, when you first push `20` and then push `5` into the stack, the first `pop` will return `5` and the second `pop` will return `20`. Therefore you calculate `5 - 20` instead of `20 - 5`.

You should reverse the order of the operands in order to make the correct computation:

```
else if (input.equals("-")) {
    int n1 = stack.pop();
    int n2 = stack.pop();
    int result = n2 - n1;
    stack.push((int)result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies for such a basic question, I am fairly new to programming and you helping with simple little mistakes like this helps me so much! Cheers again

Comment: Same applies to division. Actually to all operators, but `+` and `*` are commutative, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user207421 that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You're popping `5` and then `20`. I.e., you need to reverse the order of subtraction:

```
int result = n2 - n1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate your help!